# CoreData Querying

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I have created a CoreData model and defined my entities and attributes.
I have also created a class(named dbInterface) of NSObject that conforms to `<NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>`  and added the following objects

```
NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
```

Here is where I am very lost.  How do I now proceed to get data from the sqlite3 file that was created?

My query, if thats the right term to use, needs to select certain records from one of my entities based on a condition.  I do not know how to write a query or anything of the sort in CoreData.

Comment: The documentation for `NSFetchedResultsController` includes detailed sample code, and six different sample apps that use it. Do you have a specific question that none of that answers?

Comment: Well now I atleast kno where to look, thank you! I was so thrown off by different sites creating model wrappers and the model object context.

Answer (score 10):

You probably do not want a NSFetchedResultsController. A results controller is typically used with a UITableViewController as a helper object to populate the table.

If that is what you want, continue. However, if you are looking for just getting the entities from the core data context, you need just a NSFetchRequest. Lets say you have a core data object called Person. Lets say we want all the entities who are named "Ryan"

```
NSFetchRequest *fetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Person"];

NSString *nameToGet = @"Ryan";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = %@", nameToGet];
[fetch setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];
if(results) {
    NSLog(@"Entities with that name: %@", results);
    for(Person *p in results) {
        NSLog(@"person = %@", p);
    }
    return results;
} else {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}

return nil;
```

So you create a fetch request. A NSPredicate is like the where conditions of a SQL statement. So you create a predicate with a format ([there are tons of options for creating predicates](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/predicates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001798-SW1)). Set the request's predicate, then tell your managedObjectContext to execute the fetch request. Any results from the request will be in the returned array. Every object in the array will be an object of type Person.

If you are looking to use the NSFetchedResultsController, it is basically the same type of thing. However, you create the controller with 1 fetch request that is immutable, so it always gets the same data. If you want different data, you would need to create another controller. If you stick to just NSFetchRequests (I sperate my data layers from my UI, so using controllers isn't very useful to me) you can query any data you want and return the results.

Comment: As you mentioned, I am NOT using a tableview...i simply want to query and search for specific records and load up into an array.  I presume this is the correct method for loading into an array?

Comment: yea, using this code above, the `results` array is the array of objects that match the predicate in the core data context

Comment: throwing an error: `for(Person *p in results)` use of undeclared identifier

Comment: Are your objects called Person? this is just a placer example.